# Minimum of Wiener process and a Constant is a Super Martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I have trouble with following problem:

Let $w_t, t \geq 0$ be the standard Wiener process. Find ALL constants $C$, for which the process $(\gamma_t := min(w_t, C))$ is a super-martingale with respect to the filtration $F_{\leq t}$ generated by $w_t$.

I think base requirements are well for all $C$, but I stuck with super-martingale inequality.

Comment: HINT: $x \mapsto \min(x,C)$ is concave.

Comment: I think I get it. Hence, is it true then that this is true for any constant?

Comment: This function is concave for any constant. Jensen's inequality does the rest.